# Development methodology for CMS driven websites

Tags: magento, methods, content-management-system, frontend

This is quite a generic question, and I hope to hear what opinions people have on this, rather than a dedicated answer.

Ive been developing for about 6 years and have recently joined a new team. I am self taught. I have been given a project to develop a Magento driven ecommerce site, and a large portion focussing on editorial/blogging sections.

When I work with a CMS (i realise not CMS's work the same), to complete a project my methods have always been in the following order:

1. Develop the front-end (html, css, js).
2. Integrate front-end templates onto CMS
3. Compile CMS functions to fill out contents in placeholders on thos templates (replacing any dummy text etc).
4. Inject content.

When I explained this to my colleagues they looked horrified.

So they work a different way around:

1. Compile functions on CMS
2. Inject content.
3. Add styles (html templates, css, js etc).

Add to the equation, my scenario, the ecommerce website im developing must be responsive on devices.

So my question is, having I been doing this wrong for the last 6 years? Complete the front-end first? Or compile the front-end after?

I would really like to hear what people think about this. I am self taught, so have never had official training on development patterns such as this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It rather depends on the system used. Some systems allow you complete flexibility in the front-end, others (such as Magento) are more restrictive in what they allow.

At [my company](http://www.onehippo.org) we usually use something akin to your preferred method; but I know that a partner of ours developed for Magento in the way of your colleagues.

So, my guess is that you both are right and that it is dependent on the choice of product.